# How can I add PdfTable to an existing pdf document with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Here is the way I open an existing pdf and add some values for the fields:

```
public static byte[] GeneratePdf(string pdfPath, Dictionary<string, string> formFieldMap)
    {
        var output                      = new MemoryStream();
        var reader                      = new PdfReader(pdfPath);

        var stamper                     = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
        var formFields                  = stamper.AcroFields;


        foreach (var fieldName in formFieldMap.Keys)
            formFields.SetField(fieldName, formFieldMap[fieldName]);

        stamper.FormFlattening          = true;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

Can you tell me how can I add a PdfTable object in this context?

Comment: `ISharpText` has some amazing documentation and examples.. have you looked on there support site..?

Comment: Right now, your question sounds like: I want to put a square peg in a round hole. You have a form with AcroForm fields. That form is **static**. Where do you want to add a `PdfPTable`? Do you want to fit a table inside a field? If so, are you sure the field is big enough? Or do you expect the field to magically resize? If so, **reconsider** because you are making the wrong assumptions about PDF forms.